# Dynamic change the value of "select" based on other select values

Tags: webforms

Is there any way (without Javascript/jQuery) to dynamically show or hide value of select options based on other fields? For example from this code:

```
event:
  '#type': select
  '#title': 'Event Information'
  '#options':
    Class1: 'Class1'
    Class2: 'Class2'
    Event1: 'Event1'
        
currency:
  '#type': select
  '#title': Currency
  '#options':
    CAD: 'Canadian Dollar(CAD)'
    USD: 'US Dollar(USD)'

fee:
  '#type': select_other
  '#title': 'Tuition Fee'
  '#options':
    50: '50'
    60: '60'
    70: '70'
    '#other_type': number
```

So I want the "fee" options changes based on "Event" and "Currency". Is it possible with Drupal Webform?

What I did as a workaround to create different "fee" and show/hike it based on "Event" and  "Currency" values but probably not a good approach. The more values I add under "fee", there more instances of "fee" select I need to create.

Versions:

- Drupal:  9.1.8
- Webform: 6.0.3

Comment: [Using Webform in Drupal 8, 2.1: Create Conditional Elements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ic4wu-iZd4Y&ab_channel=WebWash)

Comment: Conditional Element is to make action(hide/visible/etc) for the entire select element. It doesn't make action for each value of the select.